# Why .mo .po files are not working with my site?

Tags: multi-language

I have a site with polylang installed with 3 languages. LV as default, EN and RU. For the PLURAR(polylang does not support it) strings translation I want to use poedit locally and then copy the translated mo/po files to the child theme /language folder. I tried to translate two string, copied the created mo/po files to the server, but the at the sites frontend transaltion is not shown. I have read multiple manuals and everything should be working, but nothing really happens.

In my child themes /languages folder I even created two types of language code files lv.mo , lv.po and lv_LV.mo and lv_LV.po but nothing happens.

My child themes function.php has definition of language folder.

```
load_child_theme_textdomain ( 'greattheme', get_stylesheet_directory () . '/languages' );
```

What could be wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Theme Handbook ⇒ Internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#internationalization), you should call `load_child_theme_textdomain()` from within the `after_setup_theme` hook:

```
function load_greattheme_textdomain() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'greattheme', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'load_greattheme_textdomain' );
```

Make sure you name your *.mo and *.po files properly (follow the link above).

Comment: Thanks! This helped and also the text domain for the string was incorrect from previous loco translate plugin experiment.